# How to call a module from a link in joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

I installed a "call me back" module in my joomla website.It displays a form when i give a position to that module.
But i want to display it after clicking a link in a pop up window.I don't know how to call that module by clicking a link.Or what url should i give to call it ?
Can anyone help please ??

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple call back module and you can't convert that into a pop-up. Instead try installing this module http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/19435 . I have used it for my website, it's working good.

Comment: Ok but how can i call that module by clicking a link??

Comment: Is it possible to call a module from link?